# Rebinding kendo grid Data in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to bind data to kendo grid and it is binding. But, column data is not fixed, i.e., the number of column keep on changing, when it hit the Data base.

Example: when It loaded for first time, it will have 4 columns and when i change my dropdown it will hit the data base and get the data as 5 columns. But, it is showing only 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand quite well what the desired functionality is. If I am not that wrong, please try using the **async** pipe `[data]="yourDataSource | async"`.

Please find the documentation here: [Kendo Grid Data-Binding](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-getting-started)

It would be great if you could share more info.